# Laravel 5.1 - Custom button STRIPE payment

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, stripe-payments

i have button of Stripe payment in my ecommerce, like this:

```
<script
src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
data-key="pk_test_yNuawoy0jUqj1GC14jwcQR5d"
data-amount="{{ $total * 100}}"
data-name="dixard"
data-description="Widget"
data-image="https://s3.amazonaws.com/stripe-uploads/acct_14s03fK9wMx3sd9Bmerchant-icon-1416180891533-icona.jpg"
data-locale="auto"
data-currency="eur"
data-id="stripe">
</script>
```

I would like cuustom this button with css style, is this possible ? how can i custom script with css?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't customize the default button with CSS but you can instead use your own button. The idea is to use [Custom Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) instead. You'll have some Javascript code to add to your page so that you can attach a click handler to your own button that will trigger Checkout automatically.

You can see a basic example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ra010dby/1/ but the idea is that you'd do something like this:

```
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh',
  token: function(token) {
      $("#stripeToken").val(token.id);
      $("#stripeEmail").val(token.email);
      $("#myForm").submit();
  }
});

$('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
  var amount = $("#amount").val() *100;
  // Open Checkout with further options
  handler.open({
    name: 'Demo Site',
    description: '2 widgets ($20.00)',
    amount: amount
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```